# Is there a way to get the IJavaElementDelta object from IResourceDelta?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm working on an Eclipse plugin that enables traceability. I am implementing a notification system that tells the user whenever a traced item changes (is removed, renamed or edited) and for that purpose I implemented an IResourceChangeListener, but that doesn't give me all the support that I want for Java elements.

For example, when I rename a Java method inside a .java file, it only tells me which file has been edited, but I would like to have the info about the method as well. I know that this can be achieved with implementing the IElementChangedListener, but is there any way around it? Do I really have to implement two listeners (ResourceListener for other files and ElementChangedListener just for java elements) or can I somehow get the IJavaElementDelta (normally obtained from the ElementChangedListener) from the IResourceDelta? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

These two deltas are completely unrelated. You need to use both listeners.

Comment: I thought so, but I would have continued to investigate if not for your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Totally agree. Trying to save a few lines of implementing a second listener would require re-implementing almost all of org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor, which receives resource change events and emits IJavaElementDeltas in 2kLOC+.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this [link example 5](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElementDelta&method=getFlags). There is some method with this description:

> Converts an `IResourceDelta` and its children into
>     the corresponding `IJavaElementDelta`s.
>     Return whether the delta corresponds to a resource on the classpath.
>     If it is not a resource on the classpath, it will be added as a non-java
>     resource by the sender of this method.

So I suppose it could be possible.

The links leads [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=che-plugins-master/plugin-java/che-plugin-java-ext-java-codeassistant/src/main/java/org/eclipse/che/jdt/internal/core/ModelUpdater.java) which should you check ass well. Method `public void processJavaDelta(IJavaElementDelta delta)`

Comment: Although the comment in this example mentions `IResourceDelta` the code doesn't seem to be anything to do with `IResourceDelta`.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I came across this example before, but there is no reference to IResourceDelta. The documentation is very strange though, as it says that it does exactly what I need it to do, but again, no sign of IResourceDelta anywhere.

Comment: @DusanKalanj The link is also to Eclipse Che code - which is a different product from 'normal' Eclipse - I'm not sure how much they have in common.